# LINQ to group a list and return a list of a custom objects which has an embedded Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a large dataset and I am trying to group this dataset by a set of fields. In this dataset I have rows(of balances) for 5 consecutive dates. My goal is to return a list of custom object which has an IDictionary field with Key as the Date and Balance as the value. I tried something like:

```
int[] DT = new int[] {20160725,20160726,20160727,20160728,20160729};
var tranformedData = 
posData
.GroupBy(p => new {p.Symbol, p.Account})
.Select(gp => new TPosModel { 
    Symbol = gp.Key.Symbol, 
    Account = gp.Key.Account, 
    Balances = new  Dictionary<int, decimal>{
    {
        gp.Where(gpi => gpi.BusDate == DT[0]).Select(gpi => gpi.BusDate),
        gp.Where(gpi => gpi.BusDate == DT[0]).Select(gpi => gpi.Balance)
    },
    {
        gp.Where(gpi => gpi.BusDate == DT[1]).Select(gpi => gpi.BusDate),
        gp.Where(gpi => gpi.BusDate == DT[1]).Select(gpi => gpi.Balance)
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This code is causing a Duplicate Key error. I got this to work by converting the Dictionary to a List of Tuple but that is not the desired final outcome. Anybody have a suggestion on how to accomplish this please.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the input class? Also the `TPosModel` class?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, Input is read form a flat file and is of the form: 
`List({Symbol="ABC.D", Account="1234-0C", BusDate=20160725, Balance=123.45},{Symbol="ABC.D", Account="1234-0C", BusDate=20160726, Balance=125.67},{Symbol="BCD.E", Account="2345-0D", BusDate=20160725, Balance=-2300.5},{Symbol="BCD.E", Account="2345-0D", BusDate=20160726, Balance=-2350.5})` 

This List needs to be converted into:
`List({Symbol="ABC.D", Account="1234-0C", Balances={[20160725,123.45],[20160726,125.67]}},{Symbol="BCD.E", Account="2345-0D", Balances={[20160725,-2300.5][20160726,-2350.5]}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to do an internal group by on the `BusDate` after you filter out any that are not in `DT` and then you need to aggregate the `Balance`.  You could use `Sum` as I have here or something else like `First().Balance`.  It just depends on how you want to handle multiple balances on the same date.

```
int[] DT = new int[] {20160725,20160726,20160727,20160728,20160729};
var tranformedData = 
posData
.GroupBy(p => new {p.Symbol, p.Account})
.Select(gp => new TPosModel { 
    Symbol = gp.Key.Symbol, 
    Account = gp.Key.Account, 
    Balances = gp.Where(gpi => DT.Contians(gpi.BusDate))
                 .GroupBy(gpi => gpi.BusDate)
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(x => x.Balance)
    });
```

As a side note you might want to store you dates as `DateTime` instead of `int`.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. This is what I did:

`... 
    Balances = gp.Where(gpi => DT.Contains(gpi.BusDate))
                           .GroupBy(gpi => gpi.BusDate)
                           .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g =>g.FirstOrDefault().Balance)`

I get a warning for possible null reference at `g.FirstOrDefault()`. I will test a bit more and mark as resolved.

Comment: @skoppisetti Acutally you could just use `First` because the groupings are garanteed to have at least one item `g => g.First().Balance`.